# Using dynamic_cast with std::exception

Tags: c++

At what condition `dynamic_cast` can be used with std::exception as in the code below?

1)

```
#include <exception>

class MyException : public std::exception
{
};

int main()
{
    std::exception * e = new MyException();

    MyException * me = dynamic_cast<MyException *>(e);

    static_cast<void>(me);

    return 0;
}
```

2)

```
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        int a = v.at(15);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e)
    {
        const std::out_of_range & oe = dynamic_cast<const std::out_of_range &>(e);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Are C++ runtime libs compiled with enabled RTTI? (And does it follow from the fact that the second example works)?

**EDIT1:**

If I compile the second example with disabled RTTI:

```
cl /std:c++17 /EHsc /GR- b.cpp
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27025.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

b.cpp
b.cpp(13): warning C4541: 'dynamic_cast' used on polymorphic type 'std::exception' with /GR-; unpredictable behavior may result
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27025.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: There is no need to use `dynamic_cast`.  `what()` is virtual and if you call it, it will do the right thing.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you write `dynamic_cast` then your design has a problem.

Comment: Standard does not contain any ways to disable RTTI so it is compiler extension and so we must know what concrete compiler you are talking about.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::exception` is irrelevant, I am trying to figure out what happens with RTTI.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I need a cross-platform/cross-compiler code. Does this code complies  with the standard or not?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky yes, it must compile and RTTI must work unless compiler is set into some non-standard mode.

Comment: @NathanOliver Does it mean that if I use a technique like `QueryIniterface` (as COM does) my design has a problem? What is the difference between `QueryIniterface` and `dynamic_cast`?

Answer (score 3):

> At what condition dynamic_cast can be used with std::exception as in the code below?

I don't think there anything that blocks you from doing that, unless you explicitly disable RTTI.

> Are C++ runtime libs compiled with enabled RTTI?

Yes.

> ```
> new MyException()
> ```

Don't do that. It's a recipe for leaks.

In your second example, you should catch the right exception type instead of casting it:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        int a = v.at(15);
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range & oe)
    {
        // ah yes, much better.
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e)
    {
        // fallback
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks like I misunderstand something important about RTTI. Could you comment my EDIT1? If C++ runtime libs compiled with enabled RTTI than std::exception should contain RTTI info? Should not it?

Comment: Figured this out. It is because In VC 2017 std::exception is completely defined in the header with its virtual destructor and virtual what function.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky `dynamic_cast` depends on RTTI. You cannot use it with RTTI disabled.