# Compatibility between modules with enabled and disabled RTTI

Tags: c++, c++17

Looks like my previous question about [std::exception and dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615170/using-dynamic-cast-with-stdexception/) was a bit wrong, but at least, as follows from the answer, now I know that C++ runtime libs are compiled with enabled RTTI (/GR+ in MSVC) and probably I can ask a better question. Consider the code below:

```
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        int a = v.at(15);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e)
    {
        e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if I compile this code with MSVC 2017 as follows with disabled RTTI:

```
cl /std:c++17 /EHsc /GR- example.cpp
```

the compiler generates Virtual Method Table (VMT) for std::exeption (that I catch) without RTTI info, because all std::exception virtual methods (destructor and what) are defined in the header file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime_exception.h`

But `std::vector` throws `std::out_of_range` which VMT contains RTTI info because C++ runtime libs are compiled with RTTI.

So an exception is thrown with RTTI in its VMT, but is caught without RTTI in the VMT. What mechanism makes this possible (makes these two VMT compatible)?

**EDIT1:**

There can be another example when I pass a polymorphic type from module1 to module2 (by value or by reference) and compile module1 with enabled RTTI and module2 with disabled RTTI. So std::exception itself is irrelevant and I used it only as an example.

Comment: What does "VMT" mean?

Comment: @NicolBolas Virtual method table.

Comment: The typical term for that is "vtable". Also, that has (almost) nothing to do with RTTI. RTTI is about `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`; you can still have `virtual` functions without those two things.

Comment: @NicolBolas IMHO: VC accesses RTTI using vtable pointer.

Comment: RTTI does not have anything to do with exception handling, it only affects dynamic_cast<> and type_info.  The metadata that catch needs is separate and only affected by /EH.

Comment: @HansPassant see EDIT1, `std::exception` is used as an example.

Comment: So what is relevant?  Make it blow up and you have a real question.  That's going to be hard to do, mixing is not a problem.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky: "*IMHO: VC accesses RTTI using vtable pointer.*" That's why I said "almost". A vtable pointer happens *regardless* of whether you compile with RTTI or not. What the RTTI flag may change is some of the contents of the vtable. Put simply, RTTI needs a vtable to handle virtual types, but virtual types *don't* need RTTI.

Comment: Why would you assume the vtables are not compatible? What knowledge do you have of the inner workings of vtables that indicates an incompatibility should arise? (Also, how do you know it's not just luck that allows your program to work?)

Comment: @JaMiT vtables are compatible of cause, but there is something that can cause some kind of incompatibility or incorrect linkage, see the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I did not ask those questions to educate myself but to help you write a better question. And I failed, since you are now caught in a contradiction. According to your comment, the vtables are unquestionably compatible, yet you do question that fact in your question. I am having trouble reconciling this...

Answer (score 2):

Even if RTTI is disable, compiler will generate it if runtime info is required by the exception handling.

Haven't find VisualStudio related doc for now.

[GCC no-rtti doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options)

-fno-rtti

Disable generation of information about every class with virtual functions for use by the C++ run-time type identification features (dynamic_cast and typeid). If you don’t use those parts of the language, you can save some space by using this flag. **Note that exception handling uses the same information, but G++ generates it as needed.** The dynamic_cast operator can still be used for casts that do not require run-time type information, i.e. casts to void * or to unambiguous base classes.

Mixing code compiled with -frtti with that compiled with -fno-rtti may not work. For example, programs may fail to link if a class compiled with -fno-rtti is used as a base for a class compiled with -frtti.